# Plot-style of matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to know why `matplotlib` outputs plots in different styles depending on which system I run the file. For example, I let the same code run twice, once on a Windows machine and once on Ubuntu system, and got the following two plots

[image: Windows version]
[image: Ubuntu version]
The information in the plots is obviously the same, but is there a special command to let `matplotlib` know that I'd, for example, would like all my plots to be produced in the "Ubuntu style" (lower of the two) version?

Comment: It's to do with the backend that is used - it's different by default for Windows and Unix. 
https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend
You can set it like this: `backend : WXAgg`

Comment: You have two different versions of matplotlib installed on both systems. Check the version via `print(matplotlib.__version__)`. Obviously you can install the same version on all your computers and get the same output. I don't know which of the two plots you call "Ubuntu style", which would be important to know for alternative solutions.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the backend though, as claimed by the other comment.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the info, I edited the question. Would still be nice to know how I could change it to the other version withou having to install different versions.

Comment: Ah yes you're right @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The upper plot is produced with a version of matplotlib >= 2.0. The lower plot is produced with a version < 2.0. The style changes are documented in the [Changes to the default style](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html).

It's hardly possible to make a matplotlib version < 2.0 produce the exact output you'd get with matplotlib >= 2.0, although you might copy the [style sheet](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) from a newer version to the old one and set the parameters accordingly.

The inverse is however possible. To get the old (classic) style in a new version of matplotlib should be possible via

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use("classic")
```